# how to encrypt/decrypt with crypto-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

I'm using crypto-js library:

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

I want to encrypt some value and decrypt them.

but it returns wrong output.

my codes:

```
import CryptoAES from 'crypto-js/aes'

componentDidMount(){
  var ciphertext = CryptoAES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
  var _ciphertext = CryptoAES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
  console.log(_ciphertext.toString(CryptoAES.Utf8));
}
```

but my console doesn't return `my message`. it returns like this:

```
6d79206d657373616765
```

Comment: I got this error message : `cannot read property 'Utf8' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used this library, but a small check shows your result is your input's ASCII code as hex string.

```
0x6d=m
...
0x65=e

6d|79|20|6d|65|73|73|61|67|65
m |y |  |m |e |s |s |a |g |e
```

So this code is working correctly. Probably that `_ciphertext.toString()` mess everything up. You need to check how to use `_ciphertext` correctly.

Answer (score 7):

```
import CryptoAES from 'crypto-js/aes';
import CryptoENC from 'crypto-js/enc-utf8';

var ciphertext = CryptoAES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
var _ciphertext = CryptoAES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
console.log(_ciphertext.toString(CryptoENC));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are getting a hexa string `6d79206d657373616765` as you can check on [this convertor](https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter) when you enter `my message` it will return you `6d79206d657373616765`

As used in the [crypto-js Documentation](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)

You need to make use of `.toString()` inside your `decrypt` method as currently you are getting hex for your `my message` and you need to convert that back to `string`, So you need to change this :

```
var _ciphertext = CryptoAES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
```

**To**

```
var _ciphertext = CryptoAES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
```

It will be like :

```
import CryptoAES from 'crypto-js/aes'

componentDidMount(){
  var ciphertext = CryptoAES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
  var _ciphertext = CryptoAES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
  console.log(_ciphertext.toString(CryptoAES.Utf8));
}
```

Comment: this is the answer, because without `.toString` the result should be object type not string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. cippertext use output algorytms.

```
ciphertext.toString("base64")
```

or

```
ciphertext.toString("hex")
```